# Strings and character array

Tags: c++, string

What is the difference between the string and character array?

How can each element of the string be accessed in C++?

Comment: Obviously no research effort whatsoever. Couldn't even be bothered with basic formatting over the _two_ sentences.

Answer (score 2):

`string` manages its own memory; this is not so with an array of `char` except as a local variable.

In both cases you can access individual elements using `[]` (but in the case of string this is actually `operator[]`).

`string` has [a lot of built-in functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5zz6weyz.aspx) that you don't easily get in a C++-friendly way with C-Strings.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be - fair enough, taking that out.  Thanks.

Comment: peer pressure is fickle. ;-) I actually preferred the previous formulation. Of course `[]` is an operator even for C strings but it’s not `operator []`.

Comment: @Konrad - yes, there is a qualitative difference between `[]` on string and arrays that is likely out of scope for this post.  I will leave this here in comments, as it cannot then be directly downvoted.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: Nonsense. There is no `operator[]` for an array of `char`; Steve was right the first time.

Answer (score -1):

In C, they are the same, a string is a char array and you have a lot of standard methods to handle them like sprintf, strcat, strcpy, strdup, strchr, strstr...

In C++, you can also use the STL string class that will provide a object oriented string that you can manipulate in an easier way. The advantage is that the code is easier to read and you don't need to allocate/deallocate memory for the strings by yourself.

Comment: Efficiency comment is likely to prove controversial if anybody can be bothered to read this question.

Comment: Is it really worth a down vote? In my experience I saw an important difference in performance, but I agree for such a basic question, I could skip this. I remove it in my post.

Comment: @Benoit - not to me, I did not -1 you.

Comment: Didn’t downvote but FYI, there is no performance difference on modern implementations of the STL. In fact, some string operations will be *faster* in C++, since querying the length of the string is an O(1) operation, whereas with C strings it’s an O(n) operation.

Comment: strings are not the same as char array. char array's are not restricted to ending with a specific character, or restricted in any way.  \0\0\0\nI rule.  is perfectly valid for a char array. A char array is not a string, it's just an array of dumb characters.

Comment: @baash05: right. We would usually use byte array and not char array in this case but it is true there is no restriction on the content. Good practice is to use unsigned char array when not storing strings except if you need the sign of course.

Comment: `string` wasn't even in the original STL, let alone the "parts of the C++ Standard Library" that some people still insist on giving the same name.